# How to set STA apartment state for wpf with netcore / net5+?

Tags: c#, wpf

Usually this is done by simply adding `[STAThread]` on the `Main` method - However with new projects there is none of that?

When i try to set my own program entry point like this:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var application = new App();
        application.Run();
    }
}
```

it says that there is more than one program entries found. So yeah - with old .net wpf this worked, how to do it with netcore3/net5+ ?

Comment: _"with old .net wpf this worked"_ -- not clear what you mean by that. The "old" WPF and the .NET Core version of WPF work exactly the same: the program entry point is generated for you, and if you were to try to explicitly create the entry point yourself, you'd get an error.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to - the automatically generated `Main` method already has that.

You can find the generated files in the appropriate `obj` directory. For example, I just ran `dotnet new wpf` from a `WpfSta` directory and this was generated as part of `obj/Debug/net5.0-windows/App.g.cs`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Application Entry Point.
/// </summary>
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "5.0.6.0")]
public static void Main() {
    WpfSta.App app = new WpfSta.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

You *can* write your own `Main` method, and then use the `StartupObject` property in your project file to specify the entry point. But if it's just for adding `STAThread`, you don't need to.